# How do I install and use Business Intelligence, without needing to reinstall Visual Studo 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, business-intelligence

A couple of months ago, I uninstalled Business Logic from my machine as I did not need it. Now I want to work on some reporting, but I am unable to find the Business intelligence tool in my Visual Studio 2010 install.

How can I download and load it up into Visual Studio 2010 or SSMS for use please?

Answer (score 4):

BIDS (SQL Server 2008/2008 R2) and SQL Server Data Tools (SQL Server 2012) are both part of the SQL Server installer (not Express Edition), not Visual Studio.

If you're using SQL Server 2008/08 R2, the Business Intelligence tools will be installed in a separate "version" of Visual Studio, which uses the Visual Studio 2008 shell.  This means that if you're running VS 2010, you'll actually appear to have 2 versions of VS installed, VS 2010 for all your normal dev and VS 2008, which will contain the BI project types only).

If it's SQL Server 2012 that you're using, the BI project types will be installed using the VS 2010 shell, so they'll be accessible when you boot up VS 2010.

Run through your SQL Server installation process and choose the relevant BI components (Analysis Services/Reporting Services/Integration Services) on the "Feature Installation" step of the installation wizard.

Comment: The only option I required from the SQL Server 2012 Dev Edition Installer was 'SQL Server Data Tools' and I was able to open dwproj in VS2010 SP1. 
I had previously installed the VS2010 SSDT from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027 but on its own this didn't solve the problem (but may still be required)